How do I create a global Mutex in ,net
I’m attempting to create a Mutex in .NET to prevent two processes from accessing the same file simultaneously.
Here’s the code I’m using in both processes:
resMutex = New Mutex(initiallyOwned:=False, "Global\My-Mutex") If Not Mutex.TryOpenExisting("Global\My-Mutex", resMutex) Then resMutex.WaitOne() End If
However, neither process seems to be waiting for the other to complete.

This question is similar to: Cross-Process Locking in C#. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
